# My flutter app has been removed from google play store multiple times due to data access issues

Tags: flutter, permissions, google-play, data-access

do I really need to insert a "Deny" button to prevent the app from accessing users data or is the allow button enough?
**could the absence of a "deny" or "reject" button be a reason for my app being repeatedly removed from the Google Play Store?**

I had already followed all the policy requirements, like data access permission, I had already showed the user an ui contains clear text telling him that the app will access his personal data and contacts and get user's affirmation through "Allow" button before starting using the app, but they still removing my app from store.

Comment: please share the exact message from Google Play for your app removal

Comment: Does the app quit if the user says deny?  Or do you not even give them a chance to say deny?

Comment: @user16930239 the message I had receive from google play store team : 
APP STATUS: REMOVED

Your app has been removed due to the policy issue(s) listed below. This
app won't be available to users until you submit a compliant update.

ISSUE FOUND: APK REQUIRES PROMINENT DISCLOSURE​

Your app is not compliant with the User Data [1] policy.

    * Your app is uploading users' Contacts, Image information without a
prominent disclosure.

Comment: @user16930239  
   * Your app is uploading users' Contacts, Image information without a
prominent disclosure.

As per Google Play’s User Data [2] policy, in cases where your app’s
access, collection, use, or sharing of personal and sensitive user data
may not be within the reasonable expectation of the user of the product
or feature in question, you must provide an in-app disclosure of your
data access, collection, use, and sharing and seek affirmative user
consent.

Comment: @user16930239
 Your use case requires a Prominent Disclosure in accordance with this
policy.

The in-app Prominent Disclosure:

    * Must comprehensively disclose how your app collects, uses and shares
user data.

     * To meet policy requirements, it’s recommended that you reference
the following example language format for Prominent Disclosure when
it’s required: “[This app] collects/transmits/syncs/stores [type of
data] to enable [”feature”], [in what scenario].”

Comment: @user16930239      * Must be within the app itself, displayed in the normal usage of the
app and not require the user to navigate into a menu or settings.
     * Cannot only be placed in a privacy policy or terms of service.
     * Cannot be included with other disclosures unrelated to personal and
sensitive user data collection.

 Requests for user consent:

     * Must be clear and unambiguous.
     * Must require affirmative user action (for example, tap to accept,
tick a check-box).

Comment: @user16930239
     * Must not interpret navigation away from the disclosure (including
tapping away or pressing the back or home button) as consent.
     * Must not use auto-dismissing or expiring messages as a means of
obtaining user consent.
     * Must be granted by the user before your app can begin to collect or
access the personal and sensitive user data.

Comment: @user16930239 ABOUT THE USER DATA POLICY

 You must be transparent in how you handle user data (for example,
information collected from or about a user, including device
information). That means disclosing the access, collection, use,
handling, and sharing of user data from your app, and limiting the use
of the data to the policy compliant purposes disclosed.

Comment: @user16930239 
    * User Data policy [3]

     * Make appropriate changes to your app (if possible), and be sure to
address the issue described above. You may also want to check your app's
store listing for compliance, if applicable.

    * Address the issue mentioned above, deactivate the non-compliant
version and upload a compliant version with an incremented version code.

Comment: @user16930239 * In addition to your Production release, if you have other release
types that you use for testing and/or quality assurance checks (for
example, Internal test, Closed, Open), please make required changes and
update those tracks as well.
     * Make sure that the non-compliant version is under the “Not
included” section of the release.

     * Double check that your app is compliant with all other Developer
Program Policies [4].

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I don't have a "deny" button in my app, so I don't give them the chance to prevent the app from accessing their data, I only have "Allow" button, if they don't want to allow they must press on back button and exit the app

Comment: From my understanding, that's the reason you're being rejected.  You need to allow them to opt out, and then take them to a screen that explains that the app will not function as well (if at all).  Neither store wants to have you *force* a user to grant permissions.